# Mapping XML data with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to turn my XML into HTML via XSLT... and based on another situation, have come up with the below. There is a "repeating table" of data in the XML @ my:myFields/my:CargoItemsSection ...   i want this data put into a table and all other fields in "my:myFields" ignored...       in practice, the XSLT below is not generating anything; I get a blank result. :(   Any ideas?

//UPDATE -- XML FILE POSTED DOWN BELOW :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-12-05T14:55:38"
    exclude-result-prefixes="my">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="my:myFields"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:myFields">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
      <tr bgcolor="skyblue">
        <th>Equ</th>
        <th>#Items</th>
        <th>Commodity</th>
        <th>Dimensions</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>CENSPC Action</th>
        <th>Quote Type</th>
        <th>Quote</th>
        <th>QM Ref</th>
        <th>QM Text</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="my:CargoItemsSection"/> 
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="my:CargoItemsSection">
    <tr align="center">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Equipment-Size" /><xsl:value-of select="my:Equipment-Type" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:NumberOfContainers" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:CommodityName" /></td>
      <td>L:<xsl:value-of select="my:Length" />,W:<xsl:value-of select="my:Width" />,H:<xsl:value-of select="my:Height" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:Weight" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:AcceptedOrRejected" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:QuoteAmountType" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:QuoteAmount" /> <xsl:value-of select="my:Currency" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:QMReferenceNumber" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="my:QuoteText" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:SPC--Special-Cargo:-myXSD-2013-04-09T08-39-48" solutionVersion="1.0.0.1816" productVersion="14.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://team.apmoller.net/sites/NNP-One-Stop-Shop/SPC%20%20Special%20Cargo/Forms/template.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.3"?>
<?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-04-09T08:39:48" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
    <my:SpecialCargoTeamSection>
        <my:ActionTaken></my:ActionTaken>
        <my:SCTComment>In order to make a detailed handling assessment and to verify unitised/OOG handling with the applicable terminals, appreciate if you can provide a provide a technical drawing (ideally) or a photo of the cargo detailing cargo configuration and location of center of gravity.</my:SCTComment>
        <my:QMAttachment xsi:nil="true"></my:QMAttachment>
        <my:ActionTakenReEval></my:ActionTakenReEval>
        <my:AmountForCounterOffer xsi:nil="true"></my:AmountForCounterOffer>
        <my:RequestedRateAmountTypeSPC></my:RequestedRateAmountTypeSPC>
        <my:formReEvalCounterOfferClicked>false</my:formReEvalCounterOfferClicked>
        <my:SCTReviewer>VPI015</my:SCTReviewer>
        <my:AssignToGSC>false</my:AssignToGSC>
        <my:frmStatusChecker>0</my:frmStatusChecker>
        <my:FinalOffer>false</my:FinalOffer>
        <my:QuoteAmountChangeCounter>0</my:QuoteAmountChangeCounter>
    </my:SpecialCargoTeamSection>
    <my:RequestTypeSection>
        <my:RequestType>OOG Quotation</my:RequestType>
        <my:RequestType_ReEval></my:RequestType_ReEval>
    </my:RequestTypeSection>
    <my:RequestFields>
        <my:SalesPerson>ARA202</my:SalesPerson>
        <my:RequestOnBehalfOf>MF_GSCSCLNEUQTCCRB\gscsclneuqtcUser</my:RequestOnBehalfOf>
        <my:Brand>SAFMARINE</my:Brand>
        <my:ContractualCustomerCode></my:ContractualCustomerCode>
        <my:ShipmentDate xsi:nil="true"></my:ShipmentDate>
        <my:CustomerOrShipperName>CEVA Logistics </my:CustomerOrShipperName>
        <my:Origin>UAE</my:Origin>
        <my:Destination>Qatar</my:Destination>
        <my:OriginPortNameOrCODE>Jebel Ali</my:OriginPortNameOrCODE>
        <my:DestinationPortNameCODE>Doha</my:DestinationPortNameCODE>
        <my:RequestComment>Phote of the cargo attached</my:RequestComment>
        <my:Region>EUR</my:Region>
        <my:PersonOnBehalfOf>

        <pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"><pc:DisplayName>MF_GSCSCLNEUQTC</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>CRB\gscsclneuqtc</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person><pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"><pc:DisplayName>Khatua, Pankaj</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>CRB\PKH025</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person><pc:Person xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls"><pc:DisplayName>Ramasamy, Vivek</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>CRB\VRA083</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person></my:PersonOnBehalfOf>
        <my:CommodityDescription></my:CommodityDescription>
        <my:WaitingOnCustomerLabelSection></my:WaitingOnCustomerLabelSection>
        <my:group7></my:group7>
        <my:group8></my:group8>
        <my:group9></my:group9>
        <my:group10></my:group10>
        <my:RequestorPerson>
            <pc:Person>
                <pc:DisplayName></pc:DisplayName>
                <pc:AccountId>ARA202</pc:AccountId>
                <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
            </pc:Person>
        </my:RequestorPerson>
        <my:DestRegion>EUR</my:DestRegion>
        <my:RequestorReference>Fw: Invitation to bid SP2013072300025 FROM AE TO QA</my:RequestorReference>
        <my:OnBehalfOfConcat>MF_GSCSCLNEUQTC;Khatua, Pankaj;Ramasamy, Vivek;</my:OnBehalfOfConcat>
    </my:RequestFields>
    <my:ReEvaluationSection>
        <my:ReasonForReevaluation></my:ReasonForReevaluation>
        <my:RequestedValidityExpireDate xsi:nil="true"></my:RequestedValidityExpireDate>
        <my:VolumePlusTimePeriod></my:VolumePlusTimePeriod>
        <my:CompetitionInformation></my:CompetitionInformation>
        <my:RequestedRateAmountType></my:RequestedRateAmountType>
        <my:RequestedRateAmount xsi:nil="true"></my:RequestedRateAmount>
        <my:RateAmountDetail></my:RateAmountDetail>
        <my:OtherReasonofReEvaluation></my:OtherReasonofReEvaluation>
        <my:AmountCurrency></my:AmountCurrency>
        <my:QMRefNumberForReEvaluation></my:QMRefNumberForReEvaluation>
        <my:ReasonForReevalSection></my:ReasonForReevalSection>
        <my:NotBASRateSubjectToSection></my:NotBASRateSubjectToSection>
        <my:OtherReasonSection></my:OtherReasonSection>
        <my:group3></my:group3>
    </my:ReEvaluationSection>
    <my:CargoItemsSection>
        <my:Length>1010</my:Length>
        <my:Width>410</my:Width>
        <my:Height>460</my:Height>
        <my:Weight>20000</my:Weight>
        <my:AcceptedOrRejected>Clarification Needed</my:AcceptedOrRejected>

        <my:QuotePdfAttachment xsi:nil="true"></my:QuotePdfAttachment>
        <my:QuoteAmountType></my:QuoteAmountType>
        <my:Currency></my:Currency>
        <my:QuoteAmount xsi:nil="true"></my:QuoteAmount>
        <my:QMReferenceNumber></my:QMReferenceNumber>
        <my:Equipment-Type>Flat Rack</my:Equipment-Type>
        <my:Equipment-Size>40</my:Equipment-Size>
        <my:CommodityName>Machinery</my:CommodityName>
        <my:group1></my:group1>
        <my:NumberOfContainers xsi:nil="true"></my:NumberOfContainers>
        <my:QuoteText></my:QuoteText>
        <my:WaitingOnCustomer></my:WaitingOnCustomer>
        <my:group5></my:group5>
        <my:field6></my:field6>
        <my:field7></my:field7>
        <my:field8></my:field8>
        <my:field9></my:field9>
    </my:CargoItemsSection>
    <my:AcceptedViewSection>
        <my:ReasonForAcceptance></my:ReasonForAcceptance>
        <my:OtherReasonOfAccept></my:OtherReasonOfAccept>
    </my:AcceptedViewSection>
    <my:RejectViewSection>
        <my:ReasonForRejection></my:ReasonForRejection>
        <my:OtherReasonForRejection></my:OtherReasonForRejection>
    </my:RejectViewSection>
    <my:FormAndButtons>
        <my:SpecialCargoType>OOG</my:SpecialCargoType>
        <my:FormAction></my:FormAction>
        <my:NonReEvalButtonSection></my:NonReEvalButtonSection>
        <my:RequestStatus>Pending SPC Review</my:RequestStatus>
        <my:LastUpdateFrom>Form</my:LastUpdateFrom>
        <my:IsFormEdit>true</my:IsFormEdit>
        <my:Approvers>VPI015; CCH052; SSJ032; JEL025; XMZ004; ABO055; PKU014; SJD015; TDA042; TRA071; KRA126; DRA108; VIR004; KLU007</my:Approvers>
        <my:ProcessStatus>Active</my:ProcessStatus>
        <my:FileName>SPC_2013-07-24T04:43:09_ARA202</my:FileName>
        <my:ReEvalViewSection></my:ReEvalViewSection>
        <my:RequestID>1</my:RequestID>
        <my:frmCurrentView>Request Form</my:frmCurrentView>
        <my:TestSection>
            <my:CurrentUser>
                <pc:Person>
                    <pc:DisplayName></pc:DisplayName>
                    <pc:AccountId>VRA083</pc:AccountId>
                    <pc:AccountType></pc:AccountType>
                </pc:Person>
            </my:CurrentUser>
            <my:field5></my:field5>
        </my:TestSection>
        <my:RequestTypeDescription>Choose this option to get a quotation for an Out Of Gauge rate based on cargo dimensions, weight, origin/destination and standard cost involved for the shipment.</my:RequestTypeDescription>
        <my:IsNewRequest>false</my:IsNewRequest>
        <my:EmailSubscription>false</my:EmailSubscription>
        <my:TestFieldData></my:TestFieldData>
        <my:frmCounterOfferDisplayHelp>Please update the details in the request form below and save to submit your counteroffer.</my:frmCounterOfferDisplayHelp>
        <my:CustomerResponse></my:CustomerResponse>
        <my:frmWaitingOnCustomerHelp>The SPC team will not review the request further until you un-tick all "Waiting on Customer" boxes.</my:frmWaitingOnCustomerHelp>
        <my:Access>Requestor</my:Access>
        <my:Engine>ClarificationResponse</my:Engine>
        <my:UndoGSCAssignment>false</my:UndoGSCAssignment>
        <my:frmCurrentUser>vra083</my:frmCurrentUser>
        <my:frmCargoLineItemValidator>0</my:frmCargoLineItemValidator>
        <my:IntroText></my:IntroText>
        <my:ListItemID>SPC2369</my:ListItemID>
        <my:RequestorEmail>mailto:ARA202?subject=Regarding Special Cargo Request SPC2369&amp;cc=</my:RequestorEmail>
        <my:RequestorMySite>http://my.apmoller.net/person.aspx?accountname=CRB%5CARA202</my:RequestorMySite>
    </my:FormAndButtons>
    <my:TimeStamps>
        <my:RepliedBy></my:RepliedBy>
        <my:RepliedOnTimestamp xsi:nil="true"></my:RepliedOnTimestamp>
        <my:CloseTimestamp xsi:nil="true"></my:CloseTimestamp>
    </my:TimeStamps>
    <my:group2>
        <my:field3></my:field3>
        <my:field4></my:field4>
    </my:group2>
    <my:group6></my:group6>
    <my:field10></my:field10>
    <my:group11></my:group11>
</my:myFields>
```

Comment: Could you put here also your XML file?

Comment: Done - XML file added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `my` prefix mapped to two different namespace URIs.  In the XML document it's

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-04-09T08:39:48
```

and in the XSLT it's

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-12-05T14:55:38
```

Thus your match and select expressions match nothing because they're looking for elements in the wrong namespace.

Comment: ahhhhhh!!! it works ! thank you so much :)) I dont really understand what the point of that address is....  but it works!

Comment: @runelynx it's not an "address" as such, but it forms part of the identity of the various elements.  In your XML you have an element whose name is effectively "`{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2013-04-09T08:39:48}myFields`" but your XSLT is looking for one whose name is "`{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-12-05T14:55:38}myFields`".  There's plenty of information on the net if you search for "XML namespaces".